# History.js and TypeScript - Historyjs is not defined

Tags: typescript, history.js

I'm trying to use History.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) with TypeScript using the DefinitelyTyped declaration file (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/history/history.d.ts)

Historyjs object is declared in History.d.ts, but when I try to use Historyjs object I get an error saying "Historyjs is not defined", I have search in history.js file and I can't find the javascript declaration for Historyjs object ...

What's happend? any ideas? thanks!!

Comment: . Is the error runtime or compile time?

Comment: its a javascrip runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is documented in the definition file. When your add the reference line,

```
/// <reference path="history.d.ts"/>
```

to the top of your file, you then have to "import" the variable like so:

```
// var Historyjs: Historyjs = <any>History;
```

You can see more about this here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/277

Answer (score 0):

Adding a TypeScript definition file does not cause the JavaScript to be automatically loaded. You still need to manually load history.js into your browser. PS: make sure you load `history.js` *before* your file.

Comment: make sure you add a reference history.d.ts in your file `/// <reference path="history.d.ts"/>`

Comment: Yes I have reference history.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ it's supposed to be `History` not `Historyjs`